# converting mysql datetime in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code in my vb.net app:

```
If reader3.GetString(6).ToString = "0000-00-00" Then
    product_detail_from_date = ""
Else
    product_detail_from_date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader3.GetString(6)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
End If
```

on this occasion, `reader3.getstring(6)` does equal `0000-00-00`

```
Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime
```

how can i stop this error showing and get the code working with the IF statement?

Comment: what is the column type, string/text or date?

Comment: Why do you store datetimes as string?

Comment: they are not as string